# Cloudflare worker is rate limited when trying to fetch the list of googlebot IPs

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I created a Cloudflare worker which attempts to fetch the JSON file from google with the list of googlebot IPs, however it fails because google responds with 429 - rate limited.

This is probably because there are other scripts running in CF which try to access google.  Is there any way around this without having to run the fetch in a different environment outside of the CF workers?

The public URL for the googlebot IPs
https://developers.google.com/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json

The fetch script runs fine when ran from a home machine for example.

Answer (score 1):

Workers `fetch()` subrequests will come from shared egress ranges (the same as https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/ips/) so they're unfortunately prone to being rate-limited quite easily.

The proper approach for rate limiting Workers is differentiating based on the `CF-Worker` request header which contains the zone name of the Worker, but very few providers take that into account unless they're catering to Workers specifically.